# How to pass a variable to the mv command to rename a file text with spaces and the variable's text in a bash (.sh) file

Tags: date, variables, unix, terminal, mv

I create a variable and store the day, date & time in it:

```
NOW=$(date "+%a %d/%m/%Y% %H:%M")
```

Then I would like to pass `$NOW` to the `mv` command to rename a file.

e.g. Create file named a.txt with a title and the current date:

```
printf "File Report (" > ~/Desktop/a.txt
echo $NOW"):\n" >> ~/Desktop/a.txt
```

Then I try to rename the file with the variable ($NOW) included in the name:

```
mv ~/Desktop/a.txt ~/Desktop/'File Report $NOW'.txt
```

What should that last line be? I also tried these two options.

```
mv ~/Desktop/a.txt ~/Desktop/'File Report' $NOW.txt
```

&

```
mv ~/Desktop/a.txt ~/Desktop/'File Report'${NOW}.txt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming a reasonably Bourne-like shell (such as bash), variable substitution does not happen inside single quotes.  You need to use double quotes:

```
mv ~/Desktop/a.txt "${HOME}/Desktop/File Report ${NOW}.txt"
```

(I'm not sure whether the curly braces are required, but they can't hurt)

You will also need to change the date command to avoid the use of slashes.  For example:

```
NOW="$(date '+%a %d-%m-%Y% %H:%M')"
```

Comment: It is being saved within a bash script. I did that however it just doesn't rename the file at all. It stays as `a.txt`. I also tried `mv ~/Desktop/a.txt ~/Desktop/"File Report ${NOW}".txt` and that didn't rename the file either

Comment: There should be an error message in that case.  Without the error message, I cannot help you.

Comment: `mv: rename /Users/MyUser/Desktop/a.txt to ~/Desktop/File Report .txt: No such file or directory` I assume the ~ is not being unfolded and I would have to put in the exact directory in the double quotes

Comment: @joshuatvernon: Try it now.

Comment: I'm now getting this error `My-MBP:Desktop me$ NOW=$(date "+%a %d/%m/%Y% %H:%M")`
`My-MBP:Desktop me$ mv ~/Desktop/a.txt "${HOME}/Desktop/File Report ${NOW}.txt"`
`mv: rename /Users/me/Desktop/a.txt to /Users/me/Desktop/File Report Sat 16/01/2016 15:08.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @joshuatvernon: Don't generate a date with slashes in it.  You can't put those in a file name, and they cannot be escaped.

Comment: It's okay I believe the issue is because OSX won't save a file with ":" in the name.

Comment: It worked once I changed the variable to not include "/" or ":". Thanks so much!

Comment: The end output was like this e.g. `NOW=$(date "+%a %d-%m-%Y% %Hh%Mm")` printed `Sat 16-01-2016 15h32m`